# Android SQLite update current table based on (sum of (current table + another table))

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I've got two tables in Android SQLite dbHelper :

**Table#1** :

```
itemName | PCS
---------+------
item1    | 5
item2    | 7
item3    | 3
```

and **Table#2** :

```
itemName | PCS
---------+------
item2    | 2
item3    | 17
```

I need to update PCS column in Table#1 , add all PCS in table#2 into table#1(sum)\

I need this output :

updated **Table#1** :

```
    itemName | PCS
    ---------+------
    item1    |  5
    item2    |  9
    item3    | 20
```

Comment: any help will be appreciated , thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery that returns the value of `pcs` from `Table2` and add it to the value of `pcs` of `Table1`:

```
update Table1
set pcs = pcs + coalesce((select pcs from Table2 where Table2.itemname = Table1.itemname), 0)
```

Comment: If you mean the typo of Table2 then thanks I edited.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan you did not copy and paste the last part of the code: `..., 0`

Comment: excuse me, yes I didn't see that :), reformat please. +1

Answer (score 0):

One option would be merging the rows of those tables through use of `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO`  statement :

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Table1(itemName,PCS)
SELECT t1.itemName, COALESCE(t1.PCS,0)+COALESCE(t2.PCS,0)
  FROM Table1 t1 
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.itemName = t1.itemName;
```

provided that the `itemName` columns are defined as primary keys.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ad5ad45f1b8a08354f6068b10231b7bd)</kbd>

Comment: Although this may work, how efficient will it be to delete all the rows of Table1 and then insert the same number of rows again?